# Ratingbar in Listview not getting set on second time Activity launch

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, ratingbar

I have a `ListView` in an Activity. Each `ListView` item contains `TextView` , `RatingBar`.

`RatingBar` style is `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Small"` as I want to use it as an indicator only. I have also enabled `isIndicator=true.`

When the Activity launches for the first time, the `ratingbar` is getting set correctly for all items.

If I press back button,and then launch Activity again, many of the item's ratingbar is not getting set. But, data is being fetched correctly, because, in the `TextView` I am setting the rating value as text. SO, there it's appearing all the time. But, not in the `RatingBar`.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: you need to maintain the state for _RatingBar_. Also use _RecyclerView_ instead of _ListView_

Comment: @Piyush I have used ViewHolder pattern with ListView. What do you exactly mean by maintain "state" for RatingBar.

Comment: @sJy Unfortunately, my company forbids to do so. The ListView block has a TextView next to ratingbar. Is that a problem? The docs says that will be a problem only if it requires user interaction. But, my ratingabr is an indicator with style small.

Comment: When the rating is changed, you need to store that value in whatever data structure is backing your adapter, so that in the future when you bind data to the row for that position, you can set the rating bar to the appropriate value.

Comment: @Karakuri My Ratingbar can not be set by user dragging on it. I don't need that. That's why kept it's style as indicaotr/small. Then why would I need to implement setOnRatingBarChangeListener ?

Note Extra : I am setting the rating of a restaurant from Google Places API. It's not that it will change every minute. I am also caching the json data in app till app closes. When that activity laucnhes first time, the lsitview displays fine. The second time launch screws up the ratingbar.

Comment: Post your `getView` or `onBindViewHolder` implementation code.